# Php IDE for inside object AutoComplete

Tags: php, ide

I can't really understand why but although PHP is used in many sites and servers side application, still there i couldn't find any decent IDE that will have full auto-complete features like other languages has.

As specially i'm talking about auto-complete after I've signed a new object in my code.

for example:

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db); //here the auto complete knew how to help me with mysqli and documentation.
    $mysqli->query("query"); //here the auto complete didn't know to auto complete and suggest me all the functions available for the $mysqli object..

?>
```

Any idea for an IDE that really know how to do the job like Eclipse knows in Java and MS Studios knows in .Net ?

Comment: Komodo Edit , Eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) by JetBrains. They make a GREAT product with amazing features. I have been using it for years and am addicted.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans is also an option, it has autocompletion and is free.